# Does large mutual information (between observations and parameter) imply the existence of a good estimator?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, markov-process, information-theory, minimax

This question concerns the standard setting for applying Fano's inequality to derive minimax bounds for a parameter estimation problem.

The goal is to estimate a parameter described by a random variable $X$ taking values $x \in \mathcal{X}$, where the set of possible parameters has bounded size, $|\mathcal{X}| = M$. I get observations in the form of a random variable $Y$, and then output an estimator $\hat{X} = f(Y)$ such that $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow \hat{X}$ is a Markov chain.

One can then use Fano's inequality to show how the best that a classifier can perform is bounded by the mutual information $I(Y:X)$ between the observations and the parameter, e.g.
\begin{equation}
P(\hat{X} \neq X) \geq 1 - \frac{ I(Y:X) + \log 2}{\log M}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
In practice, Eq. (1) is useful for showing that a classifier is guaranteed to fail if the mutual information between observations $Y$ and parameter $X$ is upper bounded like $I(Y:X) \ll \log M$.

---

My question is, if $I(Y:X)$ can be *lower bounded*, does this imply the *existence* of an estimation scheme $f$ (with minimal assumptions) such that $P(\hat{X} \neq X)$ can be *upper bounded*? Otherwise what is a simple counterexample (again, with minimal assumptions)?

More informally, if Fano's inequality (and the data processing inequality therein) says "garbage in $\Rightarrow$ garbage out", is there some statement like "(not garbage) in $\Rightarrow$ some way to get (not garbage) out"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For instance, the error of an *optimal* estimator (i.e. maximum a posteriori estimator) may be *upper bounded* in terms of $H(X|Y)$. If we let the random variable $\hat{X}$ describing our estimator take values according to
\begin{equation}
\hat{x}(y) = \arg\max_{x} \text{Pr}(X=x|Y=y), \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Then an example of such a bound is,
\begin{equation}
  \phi^*(\text{Pr}(\hat{X} \neq X)) \leq H(X|Y),
\end{equation}
where $\phi^*$ is defined in ([Feder, 1994](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/272494)) but is most importantly monotonic. For example, if  $\text{Pr}(\hat{X} \neq X) \leq 1/2$ (e.g. in the case of binary random variables) this rearranges to

\begin{equation}
\text{Pr}(\hat{X} \neq X) \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(H(X) - I(X:Y)\right),
\end{equation}
which recovers the expected $\text{Pr}(\hat{X} \neq X)=0$ when $I(Y:X) = H(X)$.

Comment: Did you learn this for a course? Just wondering what kind of stats course you'd learn this in.. really fascinating work.

Comment: I've been working on a research project related to sufficient conditions for successful estimation and stumbled on the linked paper completely by accident!